# Solving a marginalization integral involving exponential distributions

Tags: probability, density-function, marginal-distribution, integral, exponential-distribution

I'm trying to solve a marginalization integral
\begin{equation}
\int p(y,w) dw
\end{equation}
in order to compute the density $p(y)$.

I assumed the following model:
\begin{equation}
y = (u+w)^2 + v
\end{equation}
in which $w$ and $v$ are independent and both follow an exponential distribution with rate equal to 1, and $u$ is a known real number. Then one can compute
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int_\mathbb{R} p(y,w) dw &= \int_\mathbb{R} p(y|w)p(w)  dw\\
 &= \int_\mathbb{R}{\bf{1}}_{\{(y-(u+w)^2)\geq0\} \cap\{w\geq0\}}\exp(-(y-(u+w)^2))\exp(-w) dw
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

The question is whether this integral can be solved analytically? does it have a closed form expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\int_\mathbb{R} p(y,w) dw &= \int_\mathbb{R} p(y|w)p(w)  dw\\
 &= \int_\mathbb{R}{\bf{1}}_{\{y-(u+w)^2\geq0\} \cap\{w\geq0\}}\exp(-(y-(u+w)^2))\exp(-w) dw\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}{\bf{1}}_{\{\sqrt{y}-(u+w)\geq0\} \cap\{w\geq0\}}\exp(-(y-(u+w)^2))\exp(-w) dw\\
&=\int_{0}^{\max\{0,\sqrt{y}-u\}}\exp(-y+(u+w)^2-w) dw\\
&=\exp(-y)\int_{0}^{\max\{0,\sqrt{y}-u\}}\exp\{(u+w)^2-w\} dw\\
&=\exp(-y+u^2)\int_{0}^{\max\{0,\sqrt{y}-u\}}\exp\{w^2+(2u-1)w\} dw\\\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The second term is of the form
$$\int_a^b \exp\{x^2\}\text{d}x$$
and thus does not allow for a closed form expression, other than calling the integral a special function, connected with [the imaginary error function](http://&=%5Cexp(-y)%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cmax%5C%7B0,%5Csqrt%7By%7D-u%5C%7D%7D%5Cexp((u+w)%5E2-w)%20dw%5C%5C).